# Apps Script: Set triggers on a new form to show sidebar or menu items

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that is creating a copy of a form. When the form is opened by the user for the first time I'd like it to display the sidebar or menus items. Is this possible before any authentication flow has occurred?

Adding an onOpen function the doesn't seemed to have worked as it's not automatically triggered unless you've already been through the authentication process.

The way add-ons work seems to be the behaviour I'd like but I'm unsure if you can create Add-ons for Forms yet.

Code samples would help please... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create menu items for a Form via onOpen() prior to the user authorizing. For example, the following will create a single menu with a single menu item:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Only creates menu item, and nothing else
  FormApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('My Menu item','myFunction')
      .addToUi();
}

function myFunction() {
   // Functionality here; may include code that requires authorization
}
```

The thing to keep in mind is that onOpen should only be used to create the menus -- it should not contain any code that requires authorization. The reason is that Apps Script allows onOpen() to run without authorization, but will prevent its execution entirely if anything inside of it requires authorization. This is a user-safety mechanism -- onOpen() is run before the user interacts with the Form, and it should never automatically run things without getting the user's permission first. Therefore, if a script hasn't been authorized, Apps Script will only allow certain tasks (like menu creation) to be performed.

For the same reason, it is important not to use global variables which access Apps Script services. Global variables are read and processed as the script file is read, and thus execute before the user can be asked to authorize. If you use global variables, it's best practice to limit them to simple constants.

You can read more about the [Apps Script Authorization Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle). This documentation focuses on the authorization of Apps Script add-ons, but much of it is relevant to regular Apps Script scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct about authorizations, the onOpen has limited functionalities because it runs without user explicit permission. You can use it to create a sidebar as well (not only menu items)

example below :

```
function onOpen() {
  var userInterface = createUi();
  var ui = formApp.getUi();
  ui.showSidebar(userInterface)
}

function createUi(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test sidebar');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(app.createLabel('This is a SideBar'));
  return app.add(panel);
}
```

As mentioned above too (but I insist ;-) be careful if you use global service calls as these are executed when EVERY function is called (including the onOpen) and might prevent your script from working as expected.